# Accessing the Polymer created DOM with JQuery

Tags: jquery, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm new to working with Polymer and I'm trying to access the DOM of a new custom element through jQuery but without success.

I'm trying to access the elements through the domReady method, when the elements initial set of children are guaranteed to exist.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Custom Element:

```
<template>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="seed-element.css" />
    <style>
        .hero-slider { max-width: 1440px; }
    </style>

    <content>

        <section class="hero-slider">
            <div class="iosSlider">        
              <div class="slider">

                 <div class="item">
                     <img src="img/imageTest1.jpg" alt="IMAGE TEST 1">
                 </div>
                 <div class="item">
                   <img src="img/imageTest5.jpg" alt="IMAGE TEST 5">
                 </div>

              </div>
           </div>
      </section>

    </content>

</template>

<script>

Polymer('seed-element', {

    domReady: function() {
    var shadowRoot = $(this.shadowRoot || this);
    var iosSliderElement = shadowRoot.find('.iosSlider');

    iosSliderElement.iosSlider({
        snapToChildren: true,
        desktopClickDrag: true,
        keyboardControls: true,
        scrollbar: true,
        scrollbarDrag: true,
        scrollbarHide: false,
        scrollbarLocation: 'bottom',
        scrollbarBackground: '#000000',
        scrollbarOpacity: '1',
        scrollbarBorderRadius: '0'
    });
    }
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.iosslider.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>seed-element Demo</title>
    <script src="../../platform/platform.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="seed-element.html">
</head>
<body unresolved>
    <seed-element></seed-element>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't say for sure, since you haven't included an example, but I'm guessing the problem has something to do with the fact that you *can't* access the Shadow DOM of a Polymer element from scripts outside of that element.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying to create a slider element. Once the DOM has loaded then the jQuery plugin is called (all files are within the custom element) but I'm still unable to access any of the children nodes. Do know how I can access them?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with Polymer, so I don't know how to answer that. I would suggest though that you edit your post to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what your code currently looks like so that others who are more familiar with Polymer than I am will be able to better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick solution to your problem is likely something like this:

```
Polymer('seed-element', {

  domReady: function() {
    var shadowRoot = this.shadowRoot || this;
    var iosSliderElement = $(shadowRoot.querySelector('.iosSlider'));

    iosSliderElement.iosSlider({
      snapToChildren: true,
      desktopClickDrag: true,
      keyboardControls: true,
      scrollbar: true,
      scrollbarDrag: true,
      scrollbarHide: false,
      scrollbarLocation: 'bottom',
      scrollbarBackground: '#000000',
      scrollbarOpacity: '1',
      scrollbarBorderRadius: '0'
    });
  }
});
```

A jsbin that doesn't use the for-pay iosSlider library: http://jsbin.com/foyodevu/2/edit

You see, `domReady` is called for each `<seed-element>` in your page, once that element has been inserted into the DOM and it's ready for you to interact with its children, so you shouldn't look for every seed-element within domReady because you probably only care about `this`, which is your newly created seed-element.

A couple other notes

- `$((this.shadowRoot || this).querySelector('.iosSlider'))` is a good way of querying a Polymer element's Shadow DOM. Another option is to give the element an id, then you could do `this.$.theElementsId`.
- In your example code above you use a `<content>` node. Note that that element type has special meaning within a shadow dom and is probably not what you want. `<content>` nodes allow the users of a web component to mix the light dom and shadow dom. For more information, see this article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/#toc-separation-separate
- I'd recommend a name that's more like `projectName-elementDescription` like `paper-input`. Maybe `jquery-iosslider`?

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks so much for your feedback. Unfortunately I'm still finding that the iosslider element does not exist on the page (when I console log it shows as length = 0 ). Sorry about that, I've included the full code now.

Comment: Hi @user3790289, I've taken a look and I think I've got it working now. jQuery.find() isn't working anymore, though I believe that it had previously. I'm not sure if the change is in platform or jquery, but fortunately `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are very fast and mature these days.

Comment: Hi @PeterBurns. Sorry I have another question related to the shadow dom. The slider plugin, iosslider, appends a scrollbar div to the slider container but unfortunately any functionality and inline styling needed is not added (it works fine when used outside of polymer). Do you know what I am missing on this?

Comment: It's probably something in iosslider that isn't dealing well with the shadow dom but without more information I couldn't say. Consider filing a bug with the iosslider devs. Does the library come with support?

Comment: Yes it does, I've been in touch with them and I'll post the answer once I know a fix. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i have created a jquery-polymer plugin that has a lot of functions that may help you dealing with polymer shadow dom

https://github.com/digital-flowers/jquery-polymer

to select any element inside a polymer element lets say

```
<my-button id='button1'></my-button>
```

first you need to get the button shadow root using

```
$("#button1").getShadowRoot()
```

this will return the button shadow root as jquery object then you can select anything inside it for example

```
$("#button1").getShadowRoot().find("ul > li:first")
```

also in your example you can use it inside your polymer component for example

```
$(this).getShadowRoot().find("li:first")
```

Note that this plugin and another plugin called jquery-ui-polymer fixes a lot of jquery and jquery ui compatibility issues with polymer project

https://github.com/digital-flowers/jquery-polymer

https://github.com/digital-flowers/jquery-ui-polymer

cheers ;)